# How to define a property that is stored differently in the DB than it is in code?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a field/property of a model that needs to be stored as a string.  However, it will be in a delimited format so in code, I want to be able to `get` and `set` it as an enumerable. I'm using EFCore to create a code-first migration with this class, so I believe the property needs to be public. Currently, I have this:

```cs
public class DropdownOptions
{
    public string Options { get; set; } = "";

    public string[] GetOptions() => Options.Split('|');

    public void SetOptions(IEnumerable<string> options) => Options = string.Join('|', options);
}
```

The trouble with this is that `Options` can be accessed directly.  My ideal end case would be for `Options` to not be accessible from outside the class.  But I don't know how to set it up so EF can set the string value, but not my code.

Any insight - even "that's as good as you're going to get.  Just be careful" would be appreciated.

Comment: [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Make that a comment and I'll accept it.  That's just what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data Transfer Objects for that (DTO).

```
public class DropdownOptions
{
    public string Options { get; set; } = "";
}

public class DropdownOptionsDto
{
    public string[] Options { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the code that gets the dropdown options from the database, do smoothing like this:

```
var dropdownOptions = _dbContext.DropdownOptions
    .Tolist()
    .Select(x => new DropdownOptionDto
    {
         Options = x.Options.Split('|')
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your property protected, so it can't be accessed outside of the class:

```
public class DropdownOptions
{
    protected string Options { get; set; } = "";
    
    [NotMapped]
    public string[] GetOptions() => Options.Split('|');

    public void SetOptions(IEnumerable<string> options) => Options = string.Join('|', options);
}
```

Modify OnModelCreating so EF can still access to your property:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<DropdownOptions>()
        .Property(typeof(string),"Options");
}
```

Override SaveChanges method, so it can take the values from all non public properties also:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            foreach (var prop in entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
            {
                entry.Property(prop.Name).CurrentValue = prop.GetValue(entry.Entity);
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```